# theintern calling /__intern/client.htm in URL

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, intern, ui-testing, web-testing

I want to run intern tests locally with selenium-standalone both of which i installed through npm.

when i go to run the tests -> "./node_modules/.bin/intern-runner" config=./pmictests/test/bit/GAT/internEx/intern

the browser starts but the url goes to http://localhost:8585/__intern/client.html?config=.%2Fpmictests%2Ftest%2Fbit%2FGAT%2FinternEx%2Fintern&basePath

As in the _intern/client.html? is not what i want 
why is this happening? i'm trying to get my head around it but been stuck on this problem for a while.

my config file looks like this:
define({

```
proxyPort: 9515,
proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:8585/',

tunnel: 'NullTunnel',
useSauceConnect: false,

capabilities: {
    'fixSessionCapabilities' : false,
    'selenium-version': '2.35.0',
    'idle-timeout': 36
},

environments: [
    { browserName: 'chrome' }
],


maxConcurrency: 3,


useSauceConnect: false,


webdriver: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444
},

suites: [ './tests/test/' ],

excludeInstrumentation: /^(?:tests|node_modules)\//
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That URL is for running unit tests. When you run `intern-runner`, it automatically loads `client.html` to run any unit test suites listed in `suites`. Once the unit tests are finished, Intern runs any functional tests listed in `functionalSuites` (which will load their own URLs).